# React/Rails: What's the syntax for passing html inside a prop in a Rails html.erb file?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, reactjs, react-props

I'm trying to get the following code to work, but I know my syntax for the HTML props are wrong. (The proptypes are set to PropTypes.any.) What's the correct syntax to allow the html code to render inside the component instead of erroring out or being printed as strings? Thank you in advance!

```
<%= react_component("components/tooltip", 
{ tooltip: '<div>Some String</div>', children: '<div>Content for tooltip</div>' }) %>
```

I've tried a lot of variations but they only work for react components that are rendered as react components usually do, but don't work inside the html.erb file:

```
<ExampleComponent prop1={["Some ", <strong>random</strong>, "words">]} />        or

<ExampleComponent prop2={<div><MyComponent></div>} />
```

Comment: I doubt this is possible, though would be open to discovering otherwise. In this case I'd work around it by creating a wrapper component for the `Tooltip` you're working with, and allowing that to pass in the JSX structure you need, taking into account the props you pass in.